How to reprogram PIC18F, if MCLR is disabled in first programming attempt?
I programmed my PIC18F2431 using a PICkit2 with internal master clear MCLR disabled. Now I can't reprogram the chip. How do I enable MCLR again?

Since my answer didn't seem to help, what software do you use with the PICkit 2?

If I disable MCLR(tied it to internally), is it able to still program using VPP on MCLR?

Any Microchip PIC can be erased and reprogrammed even when the configuration words have select the MCLR/VPP as a digital input. This is done using the high voltage programming method. This only fails when the MCLR/VPP pin on the controller cannot be set to a high enough voltage to allow the controller to enter the programming mode.

but my PICKIT2 shows 'programming failed at program memory address 0x0000' , New Controllers also same behavior

I use Pickit2 Programmer software

I also protect the boot loader code area section, and now this area is not re programming again.

Problem Solved, Problem was the VDD Supply voltage which must be greater then 5.0 volts, PICKIT2 was supplying 4.3 Volts, I supplied external VDD of >5.0 Volts, then issue resolved. No issue with MCLR pin.

I just have to assume that by "MCLR disabled" you mean the MCLRE bit in CONFIG3H. This should have no effect on using the PICkit 2 for programming, especially not in the standard "high voltage" mode.
Microchip has a guide for programming the PIC18F2431, Flash Microcontroller Programming Specification. Read chapter 2.4 and make sure that nothing external to the microcontroller interferes with the signals. For extra bonus points you could hook up a simple logic analyzer or oscilloscope to those pins and see if they actually conform to the documentation.
I suspect that you changed MCLR to an input, and now you have something on your circuit board that drives that pin low or high causing problems for PICkit trying to control it. It will normally need to drive it up to 12 volts.

I am connecting PIC18F2431 to pickit2 by removing it from the application circuit, Yes I make MCLR as input and tied MCLR internally to VDD, Is High Voltage programming still work using PICKIT2 when MCLR is internally tied to VDD?
